# Chart.js line graph-removing labels on the line

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js with C# and Ajax calls. I am trying to develop my first line graph. I have circles, on the line, for each data point. However, each data point is showing the value inside the circle. How do I remove this value, so it is just a blue dot?

I am using the DataLabels library. I tried many options yesterday but could not remove the numbers from the points on the line.

This is the full function  for my line graph:-

```
function LoadChart5() {
        var processType = "";

        var sdt = $("[id*=startDate]").val();
        var edt = $("[id*=endDate]").val();
        var sd = moment(sdt, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var ed = moment(edt, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $('[id*=processType] :selected').each(function (i, selected) {

            if (i == 0) {
                processType = $(selected).val();
            }
            else {
                processType = processType + "\\',\\'" + $(selected).val();
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ewDashboard.aspx/GetChart5",
            data: "{sd: '" + sd + "', ed: '" + ed + "', processType: '" + processType + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var labels = r.d[0];
                var series1 = r.d[1];
                var data = {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Process Count',
                        data: series1,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: "blue",
                        color: "red",
                        backgroundColor: "blue",
                        radius: 10,

                    }
                    ]
                };

                $("#dvChart5").html("");
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                $("#dvChart5")[0].appendChild(canvas);

                var ctx2 = canvas.getContext('2d');

                var piechart = new Chart(ctx2, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: data,
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    minRotation: 75,
                                    maxRotation: 90,
                                    fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontStyle: "bold",
                                    fontColor: "#545454",
                                    autoSkip: false
                                }
                            }],

                        },

                        tooltips: {
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('There was an error.');
            }
        });
    }
```

thanks

Comment: This code is incomplete, please post a working code or create a fiddle.

Comment: Are you using data labels plugins?

Comment: I have added the full function. Yes I am using the data labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in `option`

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        display: false,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
}
```